# How to print the object data in the page in ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to get data from FIREBASE in ionic3 and print all of them in the page. I get the data, I log it in console, everything is fine, I see the results. But it is as an object. I want to get specific data from that object, through {{object.data}} , where 'object' = object's name and 'data' = what i want from that object. But it does not give any output, instead it gives error.

I am sorry, I am new in here, see my code in the image provided. Thank you.

***This is my home.ts file***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, IonicPage, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ShoppingListService } from '../../services/shopping-list.service'; 

import { Item } from '../../models/items/item.interface';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; 

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    shoppingList$: Observable<Item[]>;
  items: any; 


  constructor(private shopping: ShoppingListService,private afDb: AngularFireDatabase,
        private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {

    //A problem here with functions or with home.html PIPE 
    //I cannot display values of shoppingList$ 

    /*this.shoppingList$ = this.shopping.getShoppingList()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .map(changes=>{ 
    return changes.map(c=>({
        key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
    }))
    }) */


     //let key = this.navParams.get('key');

     this.afDb.object(`shopping-list`).valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{
       console.log(data);
       this.items = data;

     })


   }

}
```

***this is my home.html***

```
<ion-content padding>

    <ion-list>
        <h2>Items</h2>   

        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
            {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: what does your console.log(data) shows?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Object { name: "huawei", price: "2300", quantity: "3" }
And after it this error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'huawei'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says you are getting only one object from the response, so you cannot use ngFor over an object, just change your template as,

```
 <ion-item>
    {{items?.name}}
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: I checked it this way also, but then it gives:  ERROR TypeError: "_co.items is undefined"

Comment: try with safe navigation operator as above with items?.name

Comment: Thank you, it got printed. But it is not printing the rest of the objects, it does only one. Because we are not looping with ''ngFor'. When I do 'ngFor' it brings another error. Can I please contact you somehow? Whatsap? Email ?

Comment: Sure sajeetharan@outlook.com

Comment: yeah thats the issue as i mentioned, were you able to sort it out?